# Matplotlib hiding specific tick lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using this to hide certain tick labels:

```
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::1]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

How can I also hide the tick lines that go along with those labels?

Answer (score 2):

```
for t in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklines()[::1]:
    t.set_visible(False)
```

Figured it out. The only difference is using `get_ticklines()` instead of `get_ticklabels()`.